# SQL Server: stored procedure for update from upload file not working properly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Help me guys, I am creating a stored procedure where I can update some of table rows in the existing table from the uploaded file, but I am having a trouble on the part where the update starts.

- `@sourceTable` = table name
- `#temp1` = uploaded file

Code:

```
BEGIN
    set @refnum = (select refnum from #records where [index] = @index)
    set @refnum = replace(@refnum, 'F', '')

    --  = '+@refnum+'(courier, stat, statdate, stat2, statdate2, stat3, statdate3, recvby, rel, pupdate)

    set @sql = '
        UPDATE ' + @sourceTable + '
        SET ' + @sourceTable + '.courier =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'', 1),
        '+@sourceTable+'.stat =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',3), 
        '+@sourceTable+'.statdate =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',4),
        '+@sourceTable+'.stat2 =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',5), 
        '+@sourceTable+'.statdate2 =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',6),
        '+@sourceTable+'.stat3 =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',7),
        '+@sourceTable+'.statdate3 =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',8),
        '+@sourceTable+'.recvby =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',9),
        '+@sourceTable+'.rel =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',10),
        '+@sourceTable+'.pupdate =  t2.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',11),
        FROM baseTable '+@sourceTable+' 

        INNER JOIN tempTable #temp1 ON baseTable.refdate + baseTable.refdate = tempTable.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',0)

        WHERE baseTable.refdate + baseTable.refdate = tempTable.dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',0)

        SELECT
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',1),
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',3),
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',4),
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',5), 
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',6),
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',7),
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',8),
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',9), 
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',10),
            dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',11)
            '
            select @sql
            print @sql
            --exec (@sql)

        SELECT 'File has been successfully uploaded', @fileDate,'success' as msg

        set @index = @index + 1
   END
```

Comment: what is the issue? and please include the printed sql statement

Comment: `Query executed successfully` but it doesn't update the table.

Comment: please incllude the full query so we can check what is wrong. The output of this one `print @sql`. If you are using ssms it is located in the messages tab after query execution

Comment: Uh, is that the whole query? You're not executing the dynamic SQL and the SQL is wrong anyway (e.g. you're declaring the table aliases before the tables themselves and you're trying to update from the table instead of the alias)

Comment: No this is not the whole query, thanks for the info I will edit my codes now.